# Disable system output in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to know how i can disable system outputs in Jupyter. I have been searching for solutions but no one worked for me. Out[40] thing is annoying.

[image]

Comment: This has been asked before. See the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516770/how-do-i-omit-matplotlib-printed-output-in-python-jupyter-notebook?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @DominicvanderPas it's been nearly 4 years since this answer, there's something called 'updates' on environnement like Jupiter.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I believe the information to still be relevant today. A simple semi-colon (;) at the end of a line should suppress the output.

Comment: @DominicvanderPas I'm working on Anaconda (latest version i believe) under MacOS, and unfortunately it's not working for me this solution.

Comment: Could you share the code so that I can run it on my computer? Hopefully I can find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon (;) at the end of the lines of code generating outputs